# Uncaught TypeError running code to populate a form field on a different html page

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I was trying to use the example from here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms

for my own uses.

The above example is accessing a form on the same page.  My example attempts to populate a field on a different page.

Here is the launcher html - launcher.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Launcher page</title>
<script>
function launch(text) {
    window.open("http://localhost/page2.html", '_blank');
    let entryform = window.document.forms.newentry;
    entryform.elements.town.placeholder = text; 
    window.focus();
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<p>Click button to launch page2 and populate edit box on form</p>
<button type="button" id="launcher" onclick="launch('Edinburgh')">populate a text field on a different page</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And the launched page - page2.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Page 2</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
     <h1>This page launched from launcher.html</h1>
  </header>

  <main>
    <form name="newentry">
      <p>Town: </p><input type="text" name="town" value="">
    </form>
  </main>
 </body>
</html>
```

But when I click the button on launcher.html I get an error on the launcher.html page:

```
entryform.elements.town.placeholder = text;

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined
  at launch (launcher.html:10)
  at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (launcher.html:20)
```

Why is this elements property undefined?

How can I fix this?

EDIT
What I really wanted to do was simple, but the window.open object returned was not ready at the point I was attempting to edit.  The really simple solution is like this:

```
function launch(text) {
    let p2win = window.open('page2.html', '_blank');
    p2win.onload = function(){
        p2win.document.forms.newentry.town.value = text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that this code...

```js
let entryform = window.document.forms.newentry;
```

is looking in the **current** window (ie `launcher.html`) for the form element. What you can do instead is save a reference to the popup window and access its elements via that reference.

```js
let popup = window.open("http://localhost/page2.html", '_blank')
let entryform = popoup.document.forms.newentry
// and so on
```

---

As an alternative, I would consider passing a query parameter to the popup page instead of trying to manipulate it externally.

For example

```js
window.open(`page2.html?placeholder=${encodeURIComponent(text)}`, '_blank')
```

and then in `page2.html`...

```html
<main>
  <form name="newentry">
    <p>Town: </p><input type="text" name="town" value="">
   </form>
</main>
<script>
let query = new URLSearchParams(location.search)
document.querySelector('form[name="newentry"] input[name="town"]')
  .placeholder = query.get('placeholder')
</script>
```

Live demo ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-archimedes-51vn2

Comment: Is that using jquery?  how would I achieve without jquery?

Comment: @AngusComber no, there is no jQuery in my answer. It's all vanilla JS

Comment: I tried: window.open(`page2.html?placeholder=${encodeURIComponent(text)}`, '_blank');  in function launcher() and as above for page2.html - but I don't get the town field populated on page2.  Any ideas?

Comment: @AngusComber any errors in your browser's dev console?